# Cannot connect OpenStack VM

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, networking, openstack

I have 116.89.189.0 public ip and in openstack vm, it allocated 116.89.189.39.
And I installed nodejs on vm(ubuntu 18.04) and started basic server.
but it doesn't works. what strange is that i can ping to 116.89.189.39 but
with my pc browser, 116.89.189.39:3000 doesn't works. 
I checked with wireshark, there are many TCP Retransmission packets and
some strange packets from 116.89.189.3 (NOT 116.89.189.39)
below things are my nodejs server example and sercurity groups settings.

[security group setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dA0uf.png)

[network topology at OpenStack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqRxb.png)

[nodejs on ubuntu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GlKC.png)

[basic server source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TrYAB.png)

Comment: Can you attach security group rules in english language plz. Most probable issue is security group rule only.

Comment: would you be able to `telnet 116.89.189.39 3000` while your nodejs basic server is on?